# Scanf skips functions

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

I am working on my assignment and this is the issue that I bumped into. In the assignment, it says that the input value for the middle initals should be this - "L. A.". However, once I run my program it prints some printf functions on the same line, skipping the scanf function. I have went through a lot of topics about that " %c" issue, but I still can not make my program run properly. Some of the variables are from .h file. The actual assignment is bigger, however it is pretty much repetative so I thought if I figure out how to fix this certain issue I will be able to finally finish my assignment.

```
int main(void){


    // Declare variables here:

    char ch;

    struct Name FullName = { {'\0'} };

    struct Address AddressInfo = { 0, '\0', 0, '\0', '\0' };

    struct Numbers PhoneInfo = { {'\0'} };

    // Display the title

    printf("Contact Management System\n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");

    // Contact Name Input:

    printf("Please enter the contact’s first name: ");
    scanf("%s", &FullName.firstName);

    printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);

    if (ch == 'y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact’s middle initial(s): ");
        scanf(" %s", FullName.middleInitial);
    }


    printf("Please enter the contact’s last name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &FullName.lastName);


    // Contact Address Input:

    printf("Please enter the contact’s street number: ");
    scanf("%d", &AddressInfo.streetNumber);
```

OUTPUT (I have highlighted input values):

```
Contact Management System
-------------------------
Please enter the contactÆs first name: *Artem*
Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): *y*
Please enter the contactÆs middle initial(s): *L. A.*
Please enter the contactÆs last name: Please enter the contactÆs street number:
```

Comment: Ideally needs the definitions of `Name`, `Address` & `Numbers`. Remember that `scanf` needs the address and I assume `&FullName.firstName` is wrong considering `firstName` to be a character array. Notice the difference in which `scanf` is used for both `firstName` & `middleInitial`.

Comment: do NOT declare a variable in a header file.  You can declare a variable in a .c file then in a header file have the statement; `extern variableType  variableName;`

Comment: the input format specifier `%s` will not input: ` *L. A.*`  because it will stop when it encounters the space.  Suggest using: `%5[^\n]`  and then the field middleInitial[] must be (at least) 6 characters long

Comment: please post the struct definitions

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` format specifier reads a sequence of characters terminated by whitespace.  When you enter `L. A.`, only `L.` gets read into `middleInitial` because it stops reading at the space and `A.` is left in the input buffer.  On the next `scanf`, it immediately reads those buffered characters so it doesn't stop to prompt for anything.

The simplest way to handle this is to leave out the space when inputting, i.e. `L.A.`.  If you want to support whitespace, you'll want to get rid of `scanf` entirely and read everything a full line at a time using `fgets`.  Note that `fgets` also reads in the trailing newline, so you'll need to strip that out.